# AWS Cloudfront and Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How does cloudfront work with Route53 routing policies?

So as I understand it CF is supposed to route requests to the nearest server, which is in effect the Route53 latency policy. So if you have an R53 hosted zone entry for your CF domain name is this done by default if you leave the routing policy as simple or do you neec to explicitly set this yourself? And if you chose another policy type (failover, geo-location etc) would that overwrite it?

Answer (score 7):

You leave it as simple.

You don't have access to the necessary information to actually configure it yourself -- CloudFront returns an appropriate DNS response based on the location of the requester, from a single, simple DNS record.  The functionality and configuration is managed transparently by the logic that powers the cloudfront.net domain, you set it and forget it, because there are no user-serviceable parts inside.

This is true whether you use an A-record Alias or a CNAME.

Any other configuration would not really make sense, because talking of failover or geolocation imply that you'd want to send traffic somewhere other than where CloudFront's algorithm would send it.

---

Now... there are cases when, *behind* CloudFront, you might want to use some of Route 53's snazzier options.  Let's say you had app servers in multiple regions serving exactly the same content.  Latency-based routing for the *origin hostname* (the one where CloudFront sends cache misses) would allow CloudFront to magically send requests to the app server closest to the CloudFront edge that serves each individual request.  This would be unrelated to the routing from the browser to the edge, though.

Comment: Fantastic-Tks Michael

Comment: So can you say then, that at a simple level, leave Cloudfront to manage the routing to origin servers (themselves behind ELB's) and just ALIAS'd A records at the Cloudfront level to manage mappings to the domain? The underlying ELB's can do things like failover routing etc

Comment: Can I ask you another question Michael? If I have cloudfront in front of an ELB (which is in a public subnet) - is there any way of restricting access to the domain name of that ELB to Cloudfront only (so it can't be reached on the public internet)?  My security guys are happy that we have a WAF  in front of CloudFront but are concerned that a WebCrawler could get to the domain name of the ELB and access the underlying web servers which would mean we need another WAF? Or as another solution could we do whole site hosting in CF and  pre populate the caches meaning we don't need an ELB at all ?

Comment: So in other words can Cloudfront be the inbound source of the ELB security group ?

Comment: No, CloudFront can't be the inbound source of the ELB security group.  CloudFront does not "host" sites -- it proxies requests to the origin server(s).  [You can restrict access to your back-end to only requests that came through your CloudFront distribution by configuring CloudFront to add a secret custom header name and value to each request it sends to you, then configure your back-end to reject any request where that's missing.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html#forward-custom-headers-restrict-access)

Comment: Separate questions should be posted as separate questions, but I discussed custom origin headers on Stack Overflow recently, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080803/restricting-website-access-by-country/35094780#35094780) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043688/aws-cloudfront-how-to-use-origin-custom-headers/35046344#35046344) -- you might find those informative.  I am also a consultant, and you can decipher my email address via [my SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot?tab=profile) if you would like to discuss your specific needs in depth.

Comment: Many thanks Michael - I've seen AWS themselves also have a blog post which suggests a lambda script to populate the ELB security group with the CF IPs. Apologies for not posting as separate questions - my bad !

Comment: You could populate the ELB security group with CF IPs but that only assures that the request came from *somebody's* CloudFront distribution -- not necessarily yours.  The custom headers solution, above, is a new feature.